# User can't edit their own list views after profile change

Tags: list-view

Strange issue encountered today:

I updated a user from System Admin to a different custom profile, making sure to give them the "Create and Customize List Views" permission, but for some reason now they can't update any of the list views they previously created.

The only thing I can think of is that they created the views as "Only visible to a Public Group", would this affect their ability to edit list views?  (Case Sharing Setting is set to "Private").

Any ideas?

Comment: you can edit the view as sys admin and check if the user has selected "Only visible to a Public Group", do you see insufficient privileges when trying to access the view or just that the user cannot edit the view?

Comment: Hi rao, so they did create the view as "Only visible to a Public Group", but they can see the view fine, just not edit it.

Comment: can you check if Manage Public List Views is selected for these users profile than the create and customize list views profile?

Comment: They only have Create and Customize List Views checked.

Comment: do the users profile have read permission atleast on which the list view is built, as per doc the users need to have read with create and configure list view. I think this should have what happened. They should have had Manage public list view permission and they created their own private list view shared between a group. When you changed their profile they lost the edit on list views.